# msxml2.xmlhttp IE 11 vs Chrome

Tags: excel, vba, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a VBA program which reads HTML contents, processes it and outputs the result onto an Excel spreadsheet.

The program runs without issue when the default browser is set to Chrome, however testing the program on a machine where IE 11 is set as the default browser results in a run-time error.

I believe that the issue relates to the following code:-

```
    Dim oDom As Object: Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlFile")

    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "http://bouch/jira/browse/MAX-1", False
        .Send
        oDom.body.innerHtml = .responseText
    End With
```

with IE 11, I don't think that the msxml2.xmlhttp is returning anything (or whatever it does return results in subsequent parts of the code issuing the fault).

I've tried msxml2.xmlhttp.3.0 msxml2.xmlhttp.6.0 but to no avail.

Is there a simple answer?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error? 429?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your response. Since I've posted it appears to have failed on another machine that runs Chrome, so I might have been a bit hasty to blame IE... I'll need to dig around a bit more.